# php function return two values

Tags: php

Why a return statement in if statement and outside if statement. Can someone please explain why this is done?

```
 public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $query = $this->db->get("Country");

            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                }
                **return $data;**
            }
            **return false;**
       }
```

why not Written this way

```
public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get("Country");

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            **return $data;**
        }else{
            **return false;**
        }

   }
```

Comment: coders are lazy, so they won't write unnecessary characters (6 extra characters!)

Comment: @Rizier123 how it's work ? return value two times ?

Comment: `return` will end the function, so if: `$query->num_rows() > 0` then it will return `$data` else `false`

Comment: Take a look at the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php. `If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both blocks of code will run in the exact same way, the first one is just a bit more elegant.

In the first example, if `($query->num_rows() > 0)` evaluates to true, then the function will *always* execute `return $data`since it is within the if statement's code block, which means nothing after that line of code in the function will be executed. So in this case, it will never reach the `return false` outside of the if statement and thus having the `else` in the second example is unnecessary.